# Crystal reports - where to put subreport

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I have a subreport which is multiple pages long, but I'm not sure where to put it in the report.

If I put it in a detail section, the report runs for a long time and generates way too much data.

If I put it in the report header, the page footer is not displayed during the subreport and there are about 150 blank pages (well, blank except for the page footer) after the subreport.

Right now, the report consists only of a report header, a page footer and the subreport (which is in the report header), but I will eventually be adding another subreport.  The reason I need to use subreports is because I need to have two groups.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way you can optimize the query for your subreport so that it runs more efficiently?  Are you sure you are not missing something in your query which is causing the extra pages?

Comment: What does your subreport show? How is it linked to the main report?

Comment: I'm working with an existing report, and I just copied the existing elements and structure and stuff to the new subreport.  It was working fine before, but now we've got all these problems, so I don't think it's the query.  The subreport just shows some information about users registered in the database and recent activity.

Comment: I can't get my subreport to populate... can you share your code on how you got it to populate. I have it going thru the list of objects, finding the subreport object and binding and verifying the data, but it doesn't show on the report. (The primary report has data, just not the sub....)